# Load a JList on a button click

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to show a `JList` whenever user clicks on a button.  Here is my code on button click event:

```
public void loadListBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
       JList myJList = new javax.swing.JList();
        myJList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        jPanel7.add(myJList);
        jPanel7.revalidate();
        jPanel7.repaint();
}
```

The problem is it is not showing any list on button click.  How to add the list on button click?

Comment: this code is not enough to understand

Comment: You should at least give us some idea of the layout you're using for jpanel7, and best provide a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Add the list to the GUI at start-up.  Keep a reference to the [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) used to create it.  On button click, fill the model.

Comment: I am using netBeans IDE to creat gui code....it uses GroupLayout.!! and i can't write the code which it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the default `FlowLayout` for `jPanel7` (and `GroupLayout` for the `JFrame` layout), the `JList` will not appear as it doesn't contain any elements so its preferred size will be `0x0`.

To allow the `JList` content to be scrollable you should place it in a `JScrollPane`. This will make it appear even when it is initially empty:

```
jPanel7.add(new JScrollPane(myJList));
```

Comment: i Have added list of data in Jlist but it is still not visible. I do't know why it is not showing jList.?

Comment: Is there any way to solve this issue because i have done a lot of coding till and this is my last functionality on this screen. I can't go from start now

Comment: Here is detailed functionality. for time shortage i asked question in short..i have a jTable on each row i have zones(Group of locations) if user click's on zone than there will be a pop up a list, that will show him available locations.

Comment: @HaseebWali: stop describing what the application does. It doesn't help. We can't debug code without seeing the code. If it's too large, then reproduce the problem in another, as simple as possible class, and paste the code of this class in your question. The class should be an SSCCE: short, self-contained, compilable example.